# Matplotlib python

Tags: python, poo, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Tengo un script en Python que posee una clase llamada "Triangle" la cual posee un método denominado "plot()", éste me retorna la gráfica de un triangulo. En este mismo Script tengo otra clase llamada "Circle" que tiene un método llamado "plot()", este me retorna la gráfica del círculo. Con lo anterior deseo crear un método en la clase "Triangle" que me grafique el triángulo y circulo en una sola gráfica a partir de sus respectivos métodos --- observen el método **(plotintrianglecircle)**. Cómo puedo lograr hacer lo anterior ?

Estoy utilizando matplotlib. Llevo bastante tiempo intentado hacerlo pero aún no lo logro.

He hecho lo siguiente en código:

Esta es la clase "Circle" :

```
class Circle():

    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def plot(self):

        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np

        alpha = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
        self.x = self.center[0] + self.radius * np.cos(alpha)
        self.y = self.center[1] + self.radius * np.sin(alpha)
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # plot circle
        ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'r-', label='Circle')
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        ax.legend()
        return ax
```

Para la clase Triangle tengo el siguiente código:

```
 class Triangle():

    def __init__(self, vertices):

        import numpy as np

        # (3, 2) Array of triangle vertices
        self.v = np.array(vertices)

    def plot(self):

        import numpy as np
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # plot triangle
        ax.plot(np.hstack((self.v[:, 0], self.v[0, 0])),
                np.hstack((self.v[:, 1], self.v[0, 1])),
                'k-', label='Triangle')
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        ax.legend()
       return ax

    def intrianglecircle(self, radius=None):

        import numpy as np

        if radius is None:
            self.radius = 0.05 * self.inradius()
        else:
            self.radius = radius
        # random number [0, 1]
        r1, r2 = np.random.random(), np.random.random()
        # x-coordinate
        px = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
            self.v[1][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][0]
        # y-coordinate
        py = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
              self.v[1][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][1]
        # center circle
        self.center = np.array([px, py])
        return Circle(self.center, self.radius)

        def plotintrianglecircle(self):

            import numpy as np

            c = Circle(self.center, self.radius)
            fig2 = c.plot()
            fig2.plot(np.hstack((self.v[:, 0], self.v[0, 0])),
                       np.hstack((self.v[:, 1], self.v[0, 1])),
                       'k-', label='Triangle')
            fig2.legend()
            return
```

Observen el método **plotintrianglecircle** de la clase **Triangle** lo que quiero es sólo reutilizar el método **plot** de la clase **Triangle** para evitar escribir las línea donde se encuenntra **fig2.plot(....)**. Cómo lo puedo hacer ?

Pueden ejecutar el código con estos datos para que observen el resultado:

```
vertices = [[2, 1.5], [4.5, 4], [6, 2]]
t = Triangle(vertices)
t.intrianglecircle(1)
t.plotintrianglecircle()
```

Sólo que deseo reutilizar el método plot de la clase **Triangle** como lo mencioné anteriormente.

Comment: No coloques codigo como imagen, sino como text.

Comment: SO no es un servicio de codificacion, como comentas muestra lo que has intentado implementar para los otros metodos, indicanos cual fue el error, y nosotros trataremos de ayudarte

Comment: @eyllanesc siguiendo tus recomendaciones adjunto fragmentos de código.

Comment: No solo adjuntes el codigo que no funciono, si no lo mas importante describe el error.

Comment: POdrias colocar la clase completa ya que no entiendo el orden de tu codigo, si es ordenado es muy sencillo encontrar el error. :P

Comment: En tu enunciado dices que has creado las clases Circle y Triangulo, podrias mostrarlo.

Comment: Ademas veo varias variables usadas pero declaradas como self.v.

Comment: Claro, la clase Triangle es bastante extensa, tiene otra serie de métodos definidos en ella. Pero @eyllanesc no veo necesario el resto de código de la clase, no está presentando ningún error con respecto a ellas. El error se encuentra al tratar de definir las dos figuras en 1 sola.

Comment: Una de las reglas de SO es que debes proveer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ya que esta respuesta puede ser utilizada por otro persona, y no le servira si no la puede entender. Es para la mejora de la comunidad.

Comment: @eyllanesc creo que con a edición que hice se puede visualizar mejor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si te he comprendido, necesitas dos cosas; compartir el eje entre ambas funciones para que se muestren en la misma gráfica y evitar que esta se muestre (`plt.show()`)cuando se llame al primer método `plot`. Sin modificar demasiado tu código y puedes simplemente recurrir a argumentos por defecto y dos condicionales. Esto te permitiría llamar a los métodos exactamente como lo haces ahora:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class Circle():
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def plot(self,  ax = None,  show = True):
        alpha = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
        self.x = self.center[0] + self.radius * np.cos(alpha)
        self.y = self.center[1] + self.radius * np.sin(alpha)
        if not ax:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # plot circle
        ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'r-', label='Circle')
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        ax.legend()
        if not show:
            return ax
        plt.show()


class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        # (3, 2) Array of triangle vertices
        self.v = np.array(vertices)

    def plot(self, ax = None,  show = True):
        if not ax:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # plot triangle
        ax.plot(np.hstack((self.v[:, 0], self.v[0, 0])),
                np.hstack((self.v[:, 1], self.v[0, 1])),
                'k-', label='Triangle')
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.grid(ls='--', lw=0.6)
        ax.legend()
        if not show:
            return ax
        plt.show()


    def intrianglecircle(self, radius=None):
        if radius is None:
            self.radius = 0.05 * self.inradius()
        else:
            self.radius = radius
        # random number [0, 1]
        r1, r2 = np.random.random(), np.random.random()
        # x-coordinate
        px = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
            self.v[1][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][0]
        # y-coordinate
        py = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
              self.v[1][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][1]
        # center circle
        self.center = np.array([px, py])
        return Circle(self.center, self.radius)

    def plotintrianglecircle(self):
        c = Circle(self.center, self.radius)
        ax = self.plot(show = False)
        c.plot(ax)
```

Ejemplo de salida (Jupyter Notebook):

```
# Graficar círculo + triángulo
vertices = [[2, 1.5], [4.5, 4], [6, 2]]
t = Triangle(vertices)
t.intrianglecircle(1)
t.plotintrianglecircle()

# Graficar triángulo por separado
t.plot()

#Graficar un círculo por separado
c = Circle((0, 0), 0.5)
c.plot()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer no hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo, tendré en cuenta tu solución. Gracias por la colaboración.